# Experiencing issue with Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to get exact age of members in a database in my query, which doctrine doesn't seem to like. Here's the sql

```
SELECT m.id from AppBundle:Member m  WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(:now, '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(m.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(:now, '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(m.dob, '00-%m-%d')) = 32  AND  m.gender = 'Male'
```

I get the error below:

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 128: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '<'
```

The same query below in plain sql gives me desired results

```
SELECT m0_.id AS id0 FROM members m0_ WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(m0_.dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(m0_.dob, '00-%m-%d')) = 32 AND m0_.gender = 'Male'
```

Please help

Comment: DQL only supports a subset of mysql functions: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions.  DATE_FORMAT is not one of them.  The link shows how to add date format.  You might be able to find a bundle with it already implemented.

Comment: I have a bundle that enables DATE_FORMAT, problem is the evaluation in the braces. I've moved to Native SQL instead. Thanks for looking though